# How to remove Git commit from a tag?

Tags: git, github

This is what was done:

```
git add test.txt
git commit
git tag foo
git push origin foo
```

Pay attention, the file `test.txt` was **not** committed to any branch. It only belongs to the tag `foo`. Now I want to remove it from the remote repository history:

```
git checkout 4b4ae4b
git log # I can see the commit in the log history
git reset HEAD~1
```

And I see:

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from 4b4ae4b
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What is next? How can I delete it entirely from the history and then make sure remote repository (in GitHub) also loses the commit?

Comment: So at start you were already in detached HEAD state, is that it? If so, `git push origin :foo` would delete the tag remotely, and the newly unreferenced commits would become candidates for garbage collection on the remote server. However, if someone pulled the tag before you could delete it, be prepared to see it back soon...

Comment: Note that what you're really doing is removing the *tag* from the *commit*. Commits exist on their own; tag names and branch names merely help Git *find* them. Commits that cannot be found—that have no path in the commit graph by which you can reach them, starting from some *name* like a branch or tag name—eventually get cleaned out by Git's garbage-collector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* the commit is only contained in the tag, you have to remove the tag:

```
git push origin :foo
```